# Preimage of a homogeneous prime ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Consider the following ring map 
$$\begin{align}
f: \mathbb{C}[y_0,y_1] & \to \mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1]\\
y_0 & \mapsto x_0^2 \\
y_1 & \mapsto x_1^2.
\end{align}$$
Let $a$ and $b$ be two complex numbers not both zero. Let $I = (bx_0-ax_1)$ be the homogeneous prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1]$ generated by $bx_0-ax_1$, and $J = (b^2y_0-a^2y_1)$ the homogeneous prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[y_0,y_1]$ generated by $b^2y_0-a^2y_1$. I want to prove that
$$f^{-1} ( I ) = J.$$

One direction is clear: $f^{-1} ( I ) \supset J$. **But how to show the other direction?**

Geometrically, the map $f$ is supposed to correspond to the following map
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{CP}^1 & \to \mathbb{CP}^1\\
[a,b] & \mapsto [a^2,b^2], \\
\end{align}$$
where we use $[x_0,x_1]$ and $[y_0,y_1]$ as the homogeneous coordinates for the source and target respectively.

Comment: Besides the answer below, you can also dehomogenize (if you do it sufficiently carefully) to get rid of the graded assumption and turn it in to a problem about polynomial rings in one variable, where this sort of thing should be very straightforwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to see it is the following. Since $((bx_0)^2 - (ax_1)^2) = (bx_0-ax_1)(bx_0+ax_1)$, it is easy to see that $JC[x_0,x_1] \subset I$. This is what you have.

For the other inclusion, first notice that $I \cap C[y_0,y_1]$ is a prime ideal. Since the extension $f$ is flat, the codimsion of $I \cap C[y_0,y_1]$ is at most that of $I$, which is $1$. Since $J$ is also a codimension 1 prime ideal contained in $I \cap C[y_0,y_1]$, $J = I \cap C[y_0,y_1]$.

Comment: I'm not sure if the ring map $f$ is flat, but at least it's integral (and even finite). So $f$ satisfies the going-up property, which implies $\text{height}\ f^{-1}(I) \leq \text{height}\ I$. If $f$ is flat, then it will satisfy the going-down property, and the conclusion will be $\text{height}\ f^{-1}(I) \geq \text{height}\ I$.

Comment: There are a few ways to see the extension is flat. The question is local, so you may localize both rings at $I$ and $J$, respectively. Then the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula shows the freeness as $y_0,y_1$ form a regular sequence on $C[x_0,x_1]$.

Comment: Ok. My previous argument on heights was wrong. Let me correct it here so the others won't be confused. The integrality of $f$ implies the incomparability property, which further implies $\text{height}\ f^{-1}(I) \geq \text{height}\ I$. The flatness of $f$ implies the going-down property, which further implies $\text{height}\ f^{-1}(I) \leq \text{height}\ I$.

Comment: Actually the extension $f$ is even free, right? Let $A = \mathbb{C}[x_0^2, x_1^2]$ and $B = \mathbb{C}[x_0, x_1]$. Then $B$ is a free $A$-module with a basis $\{1,x_0,x_1,x_0x_1\}$, is it?